# Discord API: как упомянуть игрока в Embed-сообщении?

Tags: discord-api

Необходим код, который может в Embed-сообщении вместо  правильно упоминать пользователя

---

Вот так отображается у меня:

[image: Не так, как надо]

А надо вот так -

[image: Надо]

Как @упомянуть пользователя в Embed-сообщении?

Answer (score 1):

```
"<@!id_пользователя>" //Айди можно скопировать включив режим разработчика в настройках
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно сделать пинг автора то используйте это

```
Embed(title = f'{ctx.author.mention}')
```

Если пинг другого человека, то `discord.Member.mention`
Если у вас есть id то можно `<@ID>` написав в тексте